# $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] reliability?

Tags: php, webserver

In one of my websites I use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to establish whether a non-registered user can see the content of a page or not.

In the manual there is written about `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`:

> The URI which was given in order to access this page; for instance,
>   '/index.html'.

My question is, is it in any client side way possible for a client to access eg. index.php even though `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` contains a different value?

I know that `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` contains the page that the client asked and that the server returns but if I don't ask myself these kind of questions once in a while I'm not happy

Also is it considered good practice to use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` in this way?

**EDIT: I included the script I use as it was too generic**

```
list($c_page) = explode('.',substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],1));
define('C_PAGE',$c_page ?: 'index');
define('LOGGED',$_SESSION['user']['id'] ?: 0);
if(in_array(C_PAGE,array('page_1','page_2','page_3')) && !LOGGED){ header('Location: login.html'); exit; }
```

Comment: Like `/index.php?foo=bar` or `/index.php/path_info`?

Comment: I included the script I use as it was too generic

Comment: You probably could have a better way to establish this kind of access restriction.

Comment: If anything comes to mind let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the serverside softwarestack you use this variable is set by the webserver or the fastcgi wrapper.

URL rewriting and non-transparent proxies in your hardware/software stack can influence the value you see within your script.

e.g. Nginx could rewrite the URL from /test.html to /index.php?action=test, then pass it to your webserver. User would have called /test.html while your application sees /index.php?action=test

Conclusion: REQUEST_URI is the URI passed to the webserver and can be used as a reference for URL-based access controls.

EDIT:

just to avoid confusion, because I've seen the other responses...

Your question as I understood:
You want to check wether your currently requesting and already password-authorized user has enough permissions to access specific URLs. Again, yes you can use the request uri as a reference value

Comment: I didn't know about REQUEST_URL. Odd it's not listed here php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php although it's mentioned in a comment. I have just done a print_r($_SERVER) on a website with Apache as webserver and REQUEST_URL wasn't available, I wonder how much support does it get?

Comment: Good point, typo caused by my general confusion of URI and URL, corrected my answer which still is valid

Comment: I'm aware that URL rewriting can be an issue for this script if it touches anything from / to . I'm not using mod_rewrite nor a proxy and that's why my question was about clients, as I said 'in any client side way'. This is still the most interesting answer though :)

Comment: Users can't tamper this value

Comment: I guess that's it, I'll keep using it then :) Accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You should really track their entrance with a session variable (or a cookie).  Either of these could be blocked...but they are closer to "foolproof".  That said, anything can be forged...so use a combination and/or strong unique strings if security is of the utmost importance.

Comment: He didn't say he wanted to replace a user login rather than checking permissions on the current URL for the current user. He needs a solid reference which can't be manipulated client-side

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I find it more reliable to declare one or more groups (classes) of users that should have access to a file, and then include a page that returns a 401 error if the logged in user if not in any of those groups. e.g.

```
session_start();
...
$access = 'admin';
include 'inc/guard.php';
```

Sounds like in your case you want 'public' and 'logged-in' which is slightly different, but is a case also covered by my guard script. There, I simply check that the `$_SESSION` variable is empty (I insert stuff into it upon log-in):

```
if($access != 'public' && empty($_SESSION)) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized', true);
    include 'inc/login.php';
    exit;
}
```